# Full outline not visible for overflowing anchor element

Tags: html, css

I have anchor tag enclosed in a p tag of fixed width.
p tag's css textoverflow: ellipsis, overflow : hidden .
when focus is on anchor tag and content overflows i.e a has a long string, right outline is not visible

what attribute can I add to make the right outline or border visible on focus for the anchor tag?

Comment: can you including a working code snippet that shows the issue.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L4kwc7ec/8/):

**HTML**

```
<p><a href="">VERY LONG TEXT AAAAAAAAAAAAARRRRRRRRRGGGGGGGGGGGHHHHHHHH</a></p>
```

**CSS**

```
p {
  background: #dedede;
  width: 200px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis; 
  overflow : hidden;
}   

p:focus-within {
  overflow : initial;
}
```